# GetDlgCtrlID for top-level window with menu bar - return value

Tags: winapi, menubar, hwnd

MSDN -> "GetDlgCtrlID function" -> Remarks: 
"... Although GetDlgCtrlID may return a value if hwndCtl is a handle to a top-level window, top-level windows cannot have identifiers and such a return value is never valid."

It seems it is wrong information - "never valid".

At least for Win2k...Win8 this return value is just kernel pointer to hmenu(bar).

And my question is (primarily to MS insiders): why MSDN so inaccurate here?

(Screenshot: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/gwl(-1)_tagwnd.png)

---

Upd (tagWND):
[image]

Also demo: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/gwl(-1)_tagwnd.zip

Comment: The MSDN provides the documented behavior. If used with parameters outside the valid range, there is no necessity to detail the error mode. The return value is not valid in this case, regardless of how reliable you assume it is. The MSDN is **accurate**. Your interpretation of formal documentation is buggy.

Answer (score 2):

It is not inaccurate.  You create a top-level window with CreateWindowEx().  Which looks like this:

```
HWND WINAPI CreateWindowEx(
  _In_      DWORD dwExStyle,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpWindowName,
  _In_      DWORD dwStyle,
  _In_      int x,
  _In_      int y,
  _In_      int nWidth,
  _In_      int nHeight,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndParent,
  _In_opt_  HMENU hMenu,
  _In_opt_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_opt_  LPVOID lpParam
);
```

Note how you don't specify the ID anywhere.  But the fine print is in the description for the `hMenu` argument:

> A handle to a menu, or specifies a child-window identifier, depending on the window style. For an overlapped or pop-up window, hMenu identifies the menu to be used with the window; it can be NULL if the class menu is to be used. For a child window, hMenu specifies the child-window identifier, an integer value used by a dialog box control to notify its parent about events. The application determines the child-window identifier; it must be unique for all child windows with the same parent window.

So you can have a menu OR a child ID.  Overloaded, pretty common in the winapi, a child control can't have a menu and a toplevel window can't have a child ID.  If you forge ahead and ignore this and call GetDlgCtrlID() on a toplevel window anyway then you *will* get back the value of the hMenu argument you specified in the create call.  Well, today, always follow the api or you might get a rude surprise some day, you'd of course use GetMenu() instead.

Comment: I must confess I do not understand the purpose of your response because its content is already represented on the selected portion of the screenshot above (see http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/gwl(-1)_tagwnd.png). Also the same information can be represented in table form (see added above). Regarding the "surprise": actually just offered to pay attention to the fact that in this case the return value has a definite meaning, and not "invalid value". (And of course no one offers to get the hMenu via a kernel pointer to the hMenu :)  ).

Comment: I must confess I do not understand the purpose of answering a question in a question nor do I know whether that screenshot came from Microsoft documentation.  Just post your own answer if you have a better one.