# Make a window a part of the desktop

Tags: winapi, user-interface, desktop

I want to make a window created with

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED, wc.lpszClassName, 0, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU, ...);
```

*a part* of the desktop. *(I know this may be impossible, but I want to get as close as possible to this feeling).*

Thus, I need that when <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is hit (or when bottom-right of the screen `Show desktop` button is clicked), the window *should not be hidden*.

**How to prevent the window to be hidden when showing desktop with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?**

[image]

*Note: I initially thought it was possible by preventing the window to be minimized
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781352/prevent-window-to-be-minimized?noredirect=1#comment43975051_27781352) but as pointed by some users, it seems
that it is another problem.*

Comment: This guy *john* from France doesn't appear to like getting phone calls from strangers. Maybe you should remove his phone number from your screenshot.

Comment: This number is nothing else than 06+12345678. People who want to do some prank calls don't need this screenshot to have the idea to call people having 0611111111 or 0606060606 or any other funny looking number @IInspectable

Comment: That explains why he stubbornly insisted that his name wasn't John.

Comment: no you didn't..... did you ? @IInspectable

Comment: Would a desk band suit your purposes?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried using `GetDesktopWindow()` as the parent window for your window? Just beware of gotchas, like: [What's so special about the desktop window?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx).

Comment: Your bounty seems wasted. You've accepted an answer. So that indicates you are satisfied. What are the concerns that need to be addressed? If you really want help you need to make it clear what you are expecting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right, I was not very clear: the only answer here was commented as quite dirty solution (to make my window child of another process I don't own : explorer.exe!)... Moreover, it leads to some error (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27856507/1422096). Thus I started this bounty to find a "better solution".

Comment: I doubt you'll get one. Not without more effort on your part to make it clear what you want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan About "effort", sorry if it's not clearly shown here in this question, but believe me, I'm fighting about this since days, and I spent countless hours on this...

Comment: I'm sure you are trying. But we don't know what you want from the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want that my window is *glued* to the desktop, like "sticky notes" sticked on your monitor. ie when WIN+D is hit, my window should still be displayed. Is it more understandable?

Comment: You could make a gadget. Anyway, it's no good writing this in comments. I'll say no more here.

Comment: This sounds a bit like Desktop Gadgets, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I don't know if that would work for WinXP though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make the window part of the desktop by doing:

```
HWND hwndOwner = GetWindow(GetWindow(GetTopWindow(0), GW_HWNDLAST), GW_CHILD);
SetWindowLong(hwndMain, GWL_HWNDPARENT, (LONG) hwndOwner);
```

Also try another test: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/quasi_owner.zip (exe + sources, tested on Win7-x86).

---

*1st version (not really working):*

It is enough remove `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` & add `WS_EX_TOPMOST`

Comment: Wouldn't WS_EX_TOPMOST put it in front of other windows, not just the desktop?

Comment: I tried @kero, and indeed, using `WS_EX_TOPMOST` makes the window in front of all windows, not just the desktop, unfortunately.

Comment: @Basj, then try SetWindowLong(your_hwnd,GWL_HWNDPARENT,quasiowner_hwnd), where quasiowner = GetWindow(GetWindow(GetWindowTop(0),GW_HWNDLAST),GW_CHILD)) = SHELLDLL_DefView = child of Progman.

Comment: @kero can you post this code with a few details in your answer (by editing the answer), I'm not sure about how to use this code

Comment: @Basj, OK, I'll do it soon (and sorry: of course, must be "GetTopWindow" instead of "GetWindowTop").

Comment: Would you have a C version (sadly, I don't know ASM) @kero?

Comment: Sorry, I have not, but it is very simple code, just a few API around the center - SetWindowLong(GWL_HWNDPARENT)...

Comment: This is about as bad as it gets. If you absolutely **must** reparent a window, do it right: [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx). And don't ignore realities, like 64-bit systems. The **Note** at [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591.aspx) has been there for roughly a decade. Irrespective of that, what you are trying cannot work reliably, unless you control both processes. Given the quality of this answer, I hope you are not on the Explorer team.

Comment: @IInspectable, obviously, you are not understand the action of SetParent, I can recommend my old tutorial demo http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/ParentOwner.zip . However, judging by my other topic here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641251/getdlgctrlid-for-top-level-window-with-menu-bar-return-value), even clarity demo may not help you, so I sympathize...

Comment: Since *I r not understand the action of `SetParent`* (dude, seriously, where do you learn to write like this?), why don't you share your collective wisdom with the rest of the community?

Comment: let's not waste time on each other, dear sir