# Error message when shutdown

Tags: c++, winapi, shutdown, explorer

When I compile the following code (with Visual C++ 2010 Express) with

```
cl test.cpp
```

and run the `.exe`, and then shutdown Windows 7, I get an error message like:

```
The instruction 0x00f....9 in explorer.exe cannot access memory at 0x00000000. Memory cannot be read.
```

I tried lots of modifications in the following code, but cannot solve this issue.
*Another remark: I'm really sure it's this program which is responsible for the crash: I don't run it, no shutdown error message, if I run it, there is one.*

**What could be the reason of the crash ?**

[Source file downloadable here](http://gget.it/b4mzdzej/test.cpp).

---

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwndMain = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED, wc.lpszClassName, 0, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU, 0, 0, 300, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwndMain, 0, 192, LWA_ALPHA);
    ShowWindow(hwndMain, nCmdShow);

    // without the next 2 lines, no crash at shutdown
    // but these 2 next lines are really important to make the main 
    // window part of the windows' desktop    
    // see comments on http://stackoverflow.com/a/27787003/1422096
    HWND hwndOwner = GetWindow(GetWindow(GetTopWindow(0), GW_HWNDLAST), GW_CHILD);   
    SetWindowLong(hwndMain, GWL_HWNDPARENT, (LONG) hwndOwner);      

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe exactly that your program is attempting to do.

Comment: Your problem is that you are making your window be owned by a window in another process without consent from that other process. Don't do that.

Comment: How would that help? It is clear that he is de-referencing a NULL pointer. Let's find it.  I strongly suspect that either hwndMain or hwndOwner is NULL, but OP has no error checkingn (tut tut! ;-)  OP, why don't you set a breakpoint in your IDe and examine those two variables?

Comment: @dandan78 Here is my small project https://github.com/josephernest/NeverForget, and the full .cpp here : https://github.com/josephernest/NeverForget/blob/master/src/neverforget.cpp.  I need the main window to be merged / blended with the desktop, thus these 2 lines

Comment: @Mawg nor hwndMain nor hwndOwner are `NULL`, because the window is created (and showed) and its owner is the Windows Desktop, as desired. The problem **only happens** when I shutdown the computer.

Comment: @Mawg Explorer is the process that has the error. It's because the asker's process made its window be owned by an explorer shell window.

Comment: Randomly changing internal window data will never end well. At the very least you should use the correct procedure to reparent a window: [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx). That will, of course, only work, if you own the target process' source code. Unless you are the owner of explorer.exe, you cannot safely do this.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, but then, how to make the window part of Windows 'desktop ? Do you mean this answer is not good : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27787003/1422096 ?

Comment: There is no supported interface to make your application part of another application. The answer you got is no good: It ignores any and all of the issues involved. A specific area of concern is that when you spread a window hierarchy across threads, those threads share the same input queue, and additional restrictions apply. Explorer.exe is not prepared for this.

Comment: The closest you can get is by using an [Active Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (only supported in Windows XP and earlier). This allowed to use a .html web page as your desktop wallpaper. Adding your application as an ActiveX control would be what you're looking for. This is not possible anymore.